# What does [A=>B] mean in a type constructor in scala

Tags: scala

Given some simple class **Container** with a type parameter T

```
case class Container[T](value:T)
```

Now defining a method

```
def test[A,B](b:Container[A=>B]) = {

}
```

What does this **[A=>B]** mean ? Is it a bound or some kinde of a function type ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a function.  It means that T is a function that takes type A as an input and returns a value of type B.

For example,

```
val c = Container[String=>Int]( s => s.length() )
c.value("abc")   // returns 3, and is the equivalent to c.value.apply("abc")
                 // which in turn calls the function s => s.length()
                 // and so returns "abc".length()
```

Comment: I was confused about the fact that T can be a function type. But now its clear

Comment: T has no constraints at all, so it can be any type, which for most people means an Object such as a String but in a functional language it also includes function.  It is a lot of the power of the language.

Answer (score 1):

The type `[A=>B]` is a function that takes inputs of type `A` and produces outputs of type `B`.

In the context of a constructor, it means you are passing in a function as a parameter to the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

A side note, for instance a function value

```
val fv = (v: Int) => v + v
```

creates a function object instance at runtime and extends `Function1` trait, which includes an `apply` method, as aforementioned. Equivalently,

```
val fv = new Function1[Int, Int] {
  def apply(v: Int) = v + v
}
```